# Add character count to custom metabox

Tags: metabox, count

I know of a way to add a character counter to the excerpt metabox in WP, but I would like to add a character counter to a custom metabox. The following script is getting the counter in the metabox, which has tabs, but it isn't counting. Any help would be great. Thanks, it's my first question in StackExchange.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#bgnp-metabox-tabs").after("<p style=\"text-align:left;\"><small>Excerpt length: </small><input type=\"text\" value=\"0\" maxlength=\"3\" size=\"3\" id=\"bgnp-metabox-tabs\" readonly=\"\"> <small>character(s).</small></p>");
    jQuery("#feed").val(jQuery("#excerpt").val().length);
    jQuery("#bgnp-metabox-tabs").keyup( function() {
        jQuery("#bgnp_metabox_tabs").val(jQuery("#excerpt").val().length);
    });
});
```

The counter appears in all of the tabs, but I only want it in the tab "#feed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the `#feed` element is the one in which you want the count value to appear?  If so, change the `#bgnp_metabox_tabs` entry in your keyup function to `#feed`.

**EDIT:**

For some reason, I wasn't seeing all the code when I first read the problem.

The id of your placeholder for the character count is the same as the id on which you are calling the `after` function.  I would change the placeholder id to something like `char-count`.

You can then target that placeholder with `jQuery(#feed #char-count)` to get it to be shown only on the feed tab (assuming the feed tab has an id of `#feed`)

Comment: I am very new to JQuery, so I just want to make sure I am replacing #feed #char-count correctly. It would replace #bgnp-metabox-tabs in the jQuery("#bgnp-metabox-tabs").keyup( function() { line?

Comment: Just to clarify:  #feed is the name of the correct tab.  #excerpt is the place where the text to be counted is located.  #char-count is the place where you want the character count number to be placed.

However, I don't know what is happening with the keyup part.  Is the user typing more text somewhere?

If these things are true:

Change the id where you have the "Excerpt Length" to char-count.

The following line should be adjusted as follows:

jQuery("#thePlaceUsersType").keyup( function() {
           jQuery("#feed #char-count").val(jQuery("#excerpt").val().length);

Comment: I would love to provide some feedback, but the caching is really giving me a problem on js and css. Cloudflare is in development mode, but it doesn't seem to be making any changes.