# Adding a character counter to the excerpt metabox

Tags: jquery, wp-admin, media-library, excerpt

We try applying an [altered version](https://gist.github.com/ellm/09900a5f43ba872419f7) of [this](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/excerpt/add-a-character-counter-to-excerpt-metabox/) (very popular) code in a custom-functions plugin. It was even mentioned at stackoverflow but the whole question was deleted since the user asking was removed. Here is a [Google cached version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:dln0P9Qm8REJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/26523571/adding-character-counter-in-wordpress-excerpt-is-effecting-page). Closely [modified code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920923/add-characters-counter-to-wordpress-title-and-excerpt) is still present.

This is the altered code:

```
// Add Character Counter to the Excerpt Meta Box
function excerpt_count_js(){
  if ('page' != get_post_type()) {

      echo '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#postexcerpt .handlediv").after("<div style=\"position:absolute;top:5px;right:80px;color:#666;\"><small>Excerpt length: </small><input type=\"text\" value=\"0\" maxlength=\"3\" size=\"3\" id=\"excerpt_counter\" readonly=\"\" style=\"background:#fff;\"> <small>character(s). (128 Characters MAX)</small></div>");
     jQuery("#excerpt_counter").val(jQuery("#excerpt").val().length);
     jQuery("#excerpt").keyup( function() {
     jQuery("#excerpt_counter").val(jQuery("#excerpt").val().length);
     if ( jQuery("#excerpt_counter").val() >= 129 ) {
        jQuery("#excerpt_counter").css("color","red");
     } else {
        jQuery("#excerpt_counter").css("color","green");
     }
   });
});</script>';
}
}
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'excerpt_count_js');
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'excerpt_count_js');
```

It works well on the excerpt meta box, producing expected results.

**But it causes multiple issues on the `Edit Media` screen**. Although it is coded to load only `if ('page' != get_post_type())` and on `admin_head-post.php` or `admin_head-post-new.php`.
These issues are:

- the `Help` and `Screen Options` buttons become un-clickable.
- the `Hover Effect` does not work on the admin sidebar
- the `Description buttons` (like <kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>+<kbd>img</kbd> etc.) just disappear.

We have tried the original as well as other modified versions of the script with no luck.

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149550/add-character-count-to-custom-metabox) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70033/excerpt-word-count) seemingly using the same jQuery coding. Still, no one has reported any issues. Is it just us?

> EDIT:

Since you asked, the errors are:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined`

Comment: Usually this is caused by a javascript error, are there any in your browser's console?

Comment: @socki03 Yes there are. I will update the question and place them in it.

Comment: @socki03 Make a note that the script is tested on a standard Wordpress v4.6.1 clean installation, with no other plugins activated using the Twenty-Fifteen theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I didn't like the way that was written, so i slightly rewrote it with different syntax, and more readable structure.

```
<?php 
// Add Character Counter to the Excerpt Meta Box
function excerpt_count_js(){
    if ('page' != get_post_type()) { ?>
        <script>

        (function($){

            $(document).ready(function(){

                if ( $('#postexcerpt').length ) {

                    var maxChar = 128;

                    $excerpt = $('#excerpt');

                    $("#postexcerpt .handlediv").after( '<div style="position:absolute;top:5px;right:80px;color:#666;">' +
                                                            '<small>Excerpt length: </small>' +
                                                            '<input type="text" value="0" maxlength="3" size="3" id="excerpt_counter" readonly="" style="background:#fff;" /> ' +
                                                            '<small>character(s). (' + maxChar + ' Characters MAX)</small>' +
                                                        '</div>'
                                                    );

                    $excerptCounter = $("#excerpt_counter");

                    $excerptCounter.val( $excerpt.val().length );

                    $excerpt.keyup( function() {

                        $excerptCounter.val( $excerpt.val().length );

                        var exColor = ( ( $excerptCounter.val() > maxChar ) ? 'red' : 'green' );

                        $excerptCounter.css( 'color', exColor );

                    });

                }

            });

         })(jQuery);

        </script>
    <?php }
}
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'excerpt_count_js');
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'excerpt_count_js');
?>
```

It didn't have a check for whether or not `#postexcerpt` was even on the page, so I added that, and attempted to clean it up and make it easier to understand and change.  I'm not a fan of the inline styling, but oh well.

Anyway, I tested this on a clean 4.6.1 install with 2016 installed, and it worked just fine.  Let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: **It works just fine**. :) Thank you so much. FYI `#postexcerpt` was in the script. But anyway. Just give us some time to test it a bit more before the final verdict (I cannot stop wondering why hasn't anyone else noticed that).

Comment: **Confirmed. No issues whatsoever**. _Please (since this is a popular script) consider upvoting the question as well. It draws more attention and helps others as well_.

Comment: I was referencing the fact that `#postexcerpt` wasn't being checked so if, for one reason or another, such as it being a Custom Post Type, or if you've disabled Excerpts on posts, the script would fail because it couldn't find a length on a value of something that doesn't exist.

Comment: I see. No. None of the above. No Custom Post Types nor disabled Excerpts. I guess it will have no issues though. Having said that. Is there a way to make sure it works fine even in those cases? If so, please consider updating your answer.